# How to fetch PDA data on a TS client

Tags: pda, typescript

I am trying to read the data on an pda account like so

```
let pdaData = awaitprogram.account.PdaAccount.fetch(pdaAccount);
```

But I am getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetch')
    at /home/jimii/Documents/crew/testProject/instructions/init.ts:106:60
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/jimii/Documents/crew/testProject/instructions/init.ts:28:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Is this a node error? I am on `v18.16.0`

Comment: Error means `program.account.PdaAccount` is undefined. Maybe you meant `program.account.pdaAccount.fetch()`? With a lowercase `p`.

Comment: @Serban, you were correct, that was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serban pointed out that it should have been a lowercase `p`.

this error arose when I was importing the IDL and ended up importing the second object, which is the types I think.